kdenlive. issue when rendering from cli command
I have a kdenlive project "video_sample.kdenlive". when trying to render it using cli, i get different errors.
kdenlive version: 24.05.0
cmd:
kdenlive_render -a video_sample.kdenlive -o output.mp4 delivery

